# What is the lower bound of n factorial

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, asymptotics, big-o-notation

The upper bound of $n!$ is $O(n^n)$. But I am not getting a way to compute the lower bound of n!.

We can write $n! = n\times(n-1)\times(n-2)\times\dots\times 1$. I can easily put all the terms as 1. The lower bound will be $\Omega(1)$. But I am not convinced with this answer.

Comment: I'm not sure you really meant "big omega of 1", but writing it more tidily doesn't make it more or less correct. If you didn't mean it, feel free to write what you meant. (See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference if you need help with the formatting.)

Answer (score 3):

There is no "the" upper/lower bound. There are as many upper/lower bounds as you want. For instance, $n!=\Omega(1), n!=\Omega(n), n!=\Omega(n^{27}), n!=\Omega(10^n)$ are all true.

What you are probably after is a tight bound. As said by Nathaniel, $\Omega(n^{n+1/2}e^{-n})$ is tight, because the ratio tends to a constant. But $\Omega(25n^{n+1/2}e^{-n}+n^{n/3}\cos(n^2))$  and $\Omega(\Gamma(n+\frac12))$  are tight bounds as well.

---

By simple means, you can establish the following bracketing:

From

$$x-1\le\lfloor x\rfloor\le x$$ you deduce
$$\log(x-1)\le \log(\lfloor x\rfloor)\le\log(x).$$ Then by integration,

$$\int_2^{n+1}\log(x-1)\,dx\le \int_2^{n+1}\log(\lfloor x\rfloor)\,dx=\sum_{k=2}^n\log(k)\le\int_2^{n+1}\log(x)\,dx.$$

So

$$n(\log(n)-1)+1\le\log(n!)\le(n+1)(\log(n+1)-1)-(2\log(2)-2)$$

or

$$e\left(\frac ne\right)^n\le n!\le \frac{e^2}4\left(\frac{n+1}e\right)^{n+1}.$$

Not as tight as Stirling, but decent.

Answer (score 2):

[Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) says that
$$n! \sim \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}$$

That means that $n!\in \Theta\left(\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\sqrt{n}\right)$ (this is a lower and upper bound).

Answer (score 2):

You can look up Stirling's formula. If you want lower bounds that are much less good but mathematically very easy:

1. n! is the product of n numbers. All but $\sqrt n$ of them are greater than $\sqrt n$, so n! > $(\sqrt n)^{n - \sqrt n}$ which is $n^{n/2 - \sqrt n/2}$.
2. n! is the product of n numbers. Half are less than n/2, and half are from n/2 to n. So you immediately get a lower bound $(n/2)^{n/2}$ and an upper bound $(n/2)^{n/2} \cdot n^{n/2}$.
3. You can split the numbers n into 4, 10 or 100 intervals instead of 2 and get better lower and upper bounds.

Answer (score 1):

It is well known that $log(n!) =\Theta(n\log(n))$. Therefore, $\exists c\in \mathbb{R}^+, 0<c\le 1$ such that:

$$log(n!)\ge cn\log(n)$$
For large enough values of $n$.

Because $e^x$ is monotonically increasing, we can order this a bit around, and get:

$$n!\ge e^{cn\log(n)}=\left(e^{\log(n)}\right)^{cn}=n^{cn}$$

Which gives a certain lower bound that depends on an unknown constant (but it is known to exist) and applies only for large enough values of $n$ (i.e, there is some $n_0$ for which the statement holds for all $n$ bigger than it)